# How do I programmatically install and enable a module?

Tags: 7, installation

There is a lot resource for doing it in Drupal 6, but I didn't find a solution for Drupal 7.

How can I install and enable selected modules?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's just one step, using [`module_enable()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_enable/7):

```
$modules = array('module1', 'module2'); // Array of module names
$enable_dependencies = TRUE; // Whether or not to enable dependant modules

module_enable($modules, $enable_dependencies);
```

Comment: Does this enable the modules in the same order as they are in the array?

Comment: No @BrentConnor, a dependency map is computed and they're installed in whatever order make sense

Answer (score 12):

Here is how you would do it with a database update using [`hook_update_N`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x) from another enabled module's `*.install` file. Then you can visit `/update.php` in the browser or run `$ drush updb` on the command line to have this code fired.

```
/**
 * Enable module1 and module2.
 */
function MYMODULE_update_7101() {

  // Array of module names.
  $modules = ['module1', 'module2'];

  // Whether or not to enable dependant modules.
  $enable_dependencies = TRUE;

  module_enable($modules, $enable_dependencies);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For drupal 8 you can use the following:

```
\Drupal::service("module_installer")->install(["my_custom_module"]);
```

In drush:

```
drush php-eval '\Drupal::service("module_installer")->install(["my_custom_module"]);'
```

Comment: If you want IDE introspection, use this: ```  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstallerInterface $moduleInstaller */
  $moduleInstaller = \Drupal::service("module_installer");
  $moduleInstaller->install(['readmehelp']);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7 there is no more [drupal_install_modules()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21install.inc/function/drupal_install_modules/6), therefore if you want to force the module installation process programmatically (if it's already enabled), you can use:

```
module_invoke('module_name', 'install');
```

To enable, it's simply:

```
module_enable(array('module_name'));
```

Or using `drush` as part of the deployment process:

```
drush -y en module_name
```