# How do I programmatically install a module?

Tags: 8, installation

For Drupal 7, I found [How do I programmatically install and enable a module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/56928)

What is the equivalent code for Drupal 8?

UPD: here [Configuration Manager or hook_update() to enable modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/191766/60214) I found the case when you can use the code during deployments, specially when your module has updates in own dependencies.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191766/configuration-manager-or-hook-update-to-enable-modules#comment231271_191781 
This comment describes what is a question about. That is true that the answer to that question partially covers the current question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use "**module_installer**" service.

```
$installer = \Drupal::service('module_installer');
// Or from the container.
$installer = $container->get('module_installer');

// Install single module.
$installer->install(['module_name']);
// Install multiple modules.
$installer->install(['module_name_1','module_name_2']);
```

Also for uninstallation of the module use the next example:

```
$installer->uninstall(['module_name']);
```