# Where to programmatically enable a Feature module

Tags: 7, hooks

I created a Drupal 7 feature and usually I would enable it with Drush, but someone suggested that I enable it with an update hook (which I assume means it gets enabled on updb or update.php).

I saw this discussion on enabling modules programmatically [How do I programmatically install and enable a module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56928/how-do-i-programmatically-install-and-enable-a-module), but it blithely skips over where to write the code. Does it go somewhere in the installation profile? Does it have to be called from another custom module that is already enabled?

I'm actually an experienced Drupaler that has somehow managed to miss this one crucial lesson, I've just been using Drush to enable modules but I want to do this the best way.

Comment: @PatrickMan – Yes, to have code inside a `hook_update_N` triggered, it needs to be placed in an enabled module.

Comment: This has been very helpful.  So if there are other features on the site that have been enabled with update hooks (by other developers), where am I likely to find those update hooks.  In a non-feature custom module?  In the installation profile?  Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickMan – Yepp, I'd scan the custom profile's or sites/all/modules/custom or sites/all/modules/features directory for `module_enable`, just this string. Than you should find it.

Answer (score 2):

A feature module is just another module. And you can enable it programmatically using the linked code from another enabled module's [`hook_update_N`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x) placed in this another enabled module's `*.install` file. This even can be another feature module. Then have this hook fired via `drush updb` on the command line or by visiting your site's `/update.php`.

You also could do that from a form submit handler. Or even from a menu callback providing some custom endpoint you can access with cURL for example.

It's safe to use other feature modules' `*.install` files. Since Features never touches `*.module` and `*.install` files during regeneration. So you are free to use them to your needs.